# multiproessing using apply and pass array as argument for each process

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

consider the case that each process need to do somthing on an array.
It seemes `Pool.apply` is the right choice for this job.

```py
def sumj(i, arr): 
    print(i, os.getpid())

    sleep(0.5)
    return np.sum(arr)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    mat = np.ones((40, 10))
    pool = Pool(processes=10)
    results = [pool.apply(sumj, args=(i, mat[i,:])) for i in range(40)]
```

```
0 1220757
1 1220758
2 1220759
3 1220760
4 1220761
5 1220762
6 1220763
```

why am I getting a serial running, pid changes but each 0.5 sec I get one row of printed data ?

Comment: just sharing info - Python and Pandas are build to efficiently use a single thread. While sharing load to other threads is good idea, one should understand that  the data a Python Thread has to now to be shared to the new threads for multi threading. So I recommend not using threading unless you have huge amount of data/files  to work with.

Comment: If the question is about `serial running pid` then it's due your system. If you have several multi threaded programs running, then you might not see them.  I think that `results` get evaluated right away in the main program and Pool runs the threads behind the screens. A study of `pool.apply` might help you here.

Answer (score 0):

[LINK](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

> apply(func[, args[, kwds]]) Call func with arguments args and keyword
> arguments kwds. It blocks until the result is ready. Given this
> blocks, apply_async() is better suited for performing work in
> parallel. Additionally, func is only executed in one of the workers of
> the pool.

```py
pool = Pool(processes=10)
results = [pool.apply_async(sumj, args=(i, mat[i,:])) for i in range(40)]
print([i.get() for i in results])
```